# How to allocate memory for char** in the most efficient way possible when we do not know exact number of words and words' length?

Tags: c, pointer-to-pointer

I am curious how to allocate memory for char** when I do not know how many words I will have and what is the maximum length of words.
I need to divide string (which I get as char*) on multiple tokens (words) and save separate words in char**.
I understand that I can allocate size for *char as (string length+1) and for each char[i] I can allocate also (string length + 1) <- in case we have the whole sting as a one token or we have each character in the string as a separate words. 
So I think the code would be:

```
char **words = malloc((strlen(str)+1) * sizeof(char*));
int i;
for( i=0; i < strlen(str)+1; i++)
 words[i] = malloc((strlen(str)+1) * sizeof(char));
```

Is it correct?
Can I do if more efficient?

Comment: Calculate the total size needed for the array and all of the strings, allocate it is one call to malloc and then fill in the block?

Comment: Efficient in speed or space?

Comment: `str` will have a length `len`.  You will get at most `len` tokens.  The _sum_ of all the memory needed for the token strings will be at most `len + len*1`.  So code needs to allocate `len` pointers and `len*2` for the all the tokens.  This can be done with a single `malloc(len*sizeof(*words) + len*2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it faster by running `strlen()` only once and saving that variable. You are also allocating way more than you need to. First find out how many words you have and allocate `char **words` by that, then for each `words[i]` allocate only enough for each word.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to allocate the memory for each word separately. Instead you can duplicate the whole string with `strdup(str)` (or `malloc(strlen(str)+1)` and `strcpy()`) and modify the copy by replacing the word delimiters with `'\0'` (as e. g. `strtok()` does).

Regarding the maximum number of words: If two back-to-back delimiters are to form an empty word between them, there can be strlen(str)+1 words; if two or more contiguous delimiter characters are considered to be a single delimiter, there can be only half as many words.